# Loop through a string array and pass its elements to a method

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a c# console application that copies files from different directories on the network and place them in one single location on the server (Win Server 2008 R2). When I run the application, I get "File not found - System.String[] 0 File(s) copied." message.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] srcPath =
            {
              @"\\sharedloc1\HR\Org Docs",
              @"\\sharedloc2\MKT\Org Docs"
            };
        string desPath = @"C:\Users\James\Desktop\my docs";

        foreach (string d in srcPath)
        {
            xcopy(srcPath, desPath + @"\");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    private static void xcopy(string[] SrcLoc, string FnlLoc)
    {

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = "copyFiles";
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + SrcLoc + "\"" + " " + "\"" + FnlLoc + "\"" + @" /d /y";
        try
        {
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            throw exp;
        }

    }
```

We have around 15 directories to loop through.

Comment: How is this building doesn't it need a comma after like     string[] srcPath =
            {
              @"\\sharedloc1\HR\Org Docs",
              @"\\sharedloc2\MKT\Org Docs"
            };

Comment: The comma got dropped when I pasted the code. I fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
foreach (string d in srcPath)
{
    xcopy(srcPath, desPath + @"\");
}
```

You should be using `d` inside the foreach:

```
foreach (string d in srcPath)
{
    xcopy(d, desPath + @"\");
}
```

You then need to change the `xcopy` method to take in a `string` instead of a `string[]`.

When you do the following:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + SrcLoc + "\"" + " " + "\"" + FnlLoc + "\"" + @" /d /y";
```

You are converting the `String[]` to a `String` (the runtime will call `.ToString()` on `SrcLoc`). This is how it ends up with `System.String[]` in your process arguments.

---

Also, this block of code does nothing except destroy the stack trace.

```
catch (Exception exp)
{
    throw exp;
}
```

If you want to re-throw and error, you should just do `throw;`.

Comment: I tried changing it to d and the method to string, but I am still getting the same results "File not found - System.String[] 0 File(s) copied."

Comment: If you are still seeing `System.String[]` you must have the wrong type still, there should be no `string[]` anywhere in `xcopy`.

Comment: Or, try putting a breakpoint on this line and examine the variables yourself: `startInfo.Arguments`

Comment: It still shows `string[]` instead of the directory path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It worked now as you mentioned. VS was acting up!